# Why does useState work with export default function but not class extends React.Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax, use-state

Let's say I have a function called Login

Why does the following syntax work with the **useState**

```
export default function Login(){

    const [user, setUser] = useState({username: '', password: ''})
```

But when you use class Login extends React.Component, an error is given? Like this

```
class Sidebar extends React.Component {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({username: '', password: ''})

  render () {
      ....
```

Comment: As @Remi Mondenx says, you don't use hooks inside a class. They are intended to give "class-like" functionality to your functional components, and you absolutely should be using fiunctional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the React documentation [here](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). React Hooks are a new paradigm and are intended to replace Classes and its logic, so this makes no sense to use hooks inside a class, that’s why it does not work.

Comment: For clarity, hooks don't replace classes, per se (slight terminology issue in your answer). The React team are clear that functional components should replace classes, and hooks give class-like functionality to functional components.

Comment: Yep exactly, thanks for the precision.